# Django MultipleChoiceField with CheckboxSelectMultiple error if only one item selected

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django form as described in the title.  It has a set of check boxes.  If two or more are selected everything works perfect.  If only one item is selected then I get "errorlist: Enter a list of values."

I have examined self.request.POST['key'] and I notice the list contains multiple entries of the same key (different value) when I select multiple choices.  It only contains one entry with one choice (makes sense).  In either case these entries are a string, not a unicode string or a list.

Is this error related to MultipleChoiceField?

CODE:

```
 # getAllChoices() returns a List([u'key', u'value'], ...)

 class TestModelForm(forms.Form):
      choices = MultipleChoiceField(label='Test Choices',
                                     choices=getAllChoices(),
                                     help_text="Testing help text",
                                     required=False,
                                     widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

UPDATE:

In the post handler for the form if I add a second item manually then all works again.  I am really thinking MultipleChoiceField demands >1 items but I cannot find this documented anywhere and if it does this makes no sense.

The following 'hack' fixes it by appending a duplicate item, this is not an  acceptable solution however.

```
 tmpList = self.request.POST.getall('installed_apps')
 if len(tmpList) == 1:
         self.request.POST.add('installed_apps', tmpList[0])
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to create this MultipleChoiceField? Does it give you a line number for your error? It seems that your implementation is attempting to do something with a list, but since MultipleChoiceField normalizes to unicode objects, it is easy to lose the *list* with one or zero objects. Also, make sure the objects you're normalizing can in fact be normalized to unicode objects. Are you handling one result differently than multiple?

Comment: I added some code.  Debugging the forms data with just 1 item.  I see that 1 item in the request.POST data and it is u'some_string'.  I also see it in the data field of the Form class, u'some_string'.  If I add two values they are still u'some_string' and u'another_string'.  So I cannot tell the difference there between one or two entries.  You are right though we treat this as a list.  Just the form.is_valid() fails with only 1 item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Django source code:

```
def clean(self, value):
    if self.required and not value:
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'], code='required')
    elif not self.required and not value:
        return self.queryset.none()
    #This line is your culprit
    if not isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['list'], code='list')
```

This raises the error indicated by `"list"` which should say `'Enter a list of values.'` Which is what you're seeing. It seems that it does in fact expect a list of values, and one cleaned value is not a list. One attempt would be to create an additional, blank element in the choices, and have it selected by default, and hidden in the form. This way, so long as they select at least one element, the POST will contain two (the chosen and the hidden), and will validate.

Otherwise, maybe a different form element is your best bet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I subclassed MultipleChoiceField and fixed its to_python method to catch this case and pass other cases to the super method.  This appears to be working fine.  Thanks!